# Extracting Text Objects from Vector Graphic Software?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.4, text

Within a Canvas X 2017 GIS file, (an ACD Systems software) I have a number of vector graphics layers, all of which contain thousands of manually entered text objects only conceptually paired with line objects (within the same layers). I hear that Canvas is similar to illustrator, although I have had too little experience with illustrator to verify this. Using Canvas's GIS capabilities, I have given my vector data spatial coordinates and then exported the layers as shapefiles. (Each layer becomes its own shapefile). However, the text objects are not transported into Arcmap (ArcGIS 10.4) within the shapefile as best as I can tell.

[image]

(Image of the data in Canvas X)

I am trying to research the best way to export the text objects and then to open them up within geospatial software. My goal is to be able to spatially associate them with their corresponding vector objects and have the GIS program populate a vector object's attribute field with the text object's text. Other formats (excluding raster) I can export the data as are TXT, PDF, and KMZ, and KML files. GIS software that I have access to include ArcGIS, QGIS, Global Mapper, and MapInfo. I have included a link to a PDF and KML sample of the data at the bottom of this post.

I would rather do this than have to export a rendered geospatial raster image, open that up side-by-side with the same layer's shapefile, and manually type the numbers into the attribute table for thousands of objects.

I have found very little on this topic online or even in person at academic institutions, but hopefully someone out there has familiarity with my question?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YpDyCUZqvSgxxdrDvSacEsN4wfPw87ex/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xxZfzPEqLwuyiMQYaIwqGO2Fip5vOG_l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you give a sample of this data? Layered PDF will work. Is your Canvas X 2017 GIS file geo-referenced?

Comment: cross post? http://forum.acdsee.com/forum/canvas/45654-editing-symbols-for-export-into-shape-file

Comment: It depends what your software does with text... it could be rendered as a font/text object, a group of graphics primitives (circle, rectangle), rasterize the labels to bitmaps... KML can be easily converted, PDF is slightly more of a challenge, but if your text objects aren't easily distinguished as *text* you will find it difficult to extract text; text objects can be quite obstinate to import/export as each package has a different idea of how to implement text and some formats do not support *text* as text. Try KML and see if your placemarks have a description in the XML.

Comment: @Mapperz Yes the file is now georeferenced. I have included a link to a PDF and KML file at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Michael Stimson I tried to experiment with exporting KML's but so far have not been able to find any data at all within my exports. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: @AlexanderAudet Looks like your Line with Box are a font (which we don't have) but got the PDF to KMZ see this https://mab.to/2RcrQmCPM (valid for 3 days)

Comment: @Mapperz How did you do that? One problem that is still present is that  the numbers are split up in the resulting KMZ, so 47 becomes a separate 4 and 7. So it looks like it might not truely work as a solution, but using ArcMap's KML to layer, it is the closest I have yet come to a solution.

Comment: I used a home license of fme [https://www.safe.com/free-fme-licenses/home-use/]  to test PDF to KML - with some time building a real workspace I am sure you can get what you want if you have the font that can be convert into an image which can be placed in the correct direction by angle. it is do-able